# How to manually fix the WordPress gallery code using PHP in functions.php?

Tags: php, functions, shortcode, gallery

It's been talked many times that Wordpress outputs some really bad code for the built-in gallery function.

This is the core code responsible for the gallery output (in /wp-includes/media.php):

```
function gallery_shortcode($attr) {
    global $post;

    static $instance = 0;
    $instance++;

    // Allow plugins/themes to override the default gallery template.
    $output = apply_filters('post_gallery', '', $attr);
    if ( $output != '' )
        return $output;

    // We're trusting author input, so let's at least make sure it looks like a valid orderby statement
    if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
        $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
        if ( !$attr['orderby'] )
            unset( $attr['orderby'] );
    }

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
        'id'         => $post->ID,
        'itemtag'    => 'dl',
        'icontag'    => 'dt',
        'captiontag' => 'dd',
        'columns'    => 3,
        'size'       => 'thumbnail',
        'include'    => '',
        'exclude'    => ''
    ), $attr));

    $id = intval($id);
    if ( 'RAND' == $order )
        $orderby = 'none';

    if ( !empty($include) ) {
        $include = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $include );
        $_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );

        $attachments = array();
        foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
            $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
        }
    } elseif ( !empty($exclude) ) {
        $exclude = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $exclude );
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $exclude, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    } else {
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    }

    if ( empty($attachments) )
        return '';

    if ( is_feed() ) {
        $output = "\n";
        foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
            $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($att_id, $size, true) . "\n";
        return $output;
    }

    $itemtag = tag_escape($itemtag);
    $captiontag = tag_escape($captiontag);
    $columns = intval($columns);
    $itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor(100/$columns) : 100;
    $float = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

    $selector = "gallery-{$instance}";

    $gallery_style = $gallery_div = '';
    if ( apply_filters( 'use_default_gallery_style', true ) )
        $gallery_style = "
        <style type='text/css'>
            #{$selector} {
                margin: auto;
            }
            #{$selector} .gallery-item {
                float: {$float};
                margin-top: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                width: {$itemwidth}%;
            }
            #{$selector} img {
                border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
            }
            #{$selector} .gallery-caption {
                margin-left: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php -->";
    $size_class = sanitize_html_class( $size );
    $gallery_div = "<div id='$selector' class='gallery galleryid-{$id} gallery-columns-{$columns} gallery-size-{$size_class}'>";
    $output = apply_filters( 'gallery_style', $gallery_style . "\n\t\t" . $gallery_div );

    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
        $link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false);

        $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
        $output .= "
            <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon'>
                $link
            </{$icontag}>";
        if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
            $output .= "
                <{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
                " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
                </{$captiontag}>";
        }
        $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
        if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
            $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
    }

    $output .= "
            <br style='clear: both;' />
        </div>\n";

    return $output;
}
```

## What I would like to fix?

**[1]** The above code outputs css style directly into the post. I want to stop that, as I can easily add the same css code in my style.css stylesheet.

**[2]** I want to disable the code from outputting captions of images below their thumbnails. I want the captions to be shown only on the attachment pages, and not in the post.

**[3]** The aforementioned code adds two `<br style="clear: both;">` elements after the gallery code. I would also like to disable that, since I can use "margin" in the css code for that.

I would like to accomplish the above "THREE" things using some PHP code in the `functions.php` file, as editing the core files is not recommended.

Hope someone can be of some help. (I don't know how to code, so, please be as much clear as possible.) Thanks!

**RELEVANT:** Source file to look at is `/wp-includes/media.php` (here's the [trunk version](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/media.php) -- look for `gallery_shortcode` function).

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Along with "pee" and "twinkle" in [wpautop](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/formatting.php#L188), it's a great example of how messy the Wordpress code is.

Comment: **Related Question:** [Modifying the default WordPress gallery template for RSS feeds](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/63980/10691) and [How do I change the gallery that is inserted in the post?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/58077/10691)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Like it was mentioned  before removing the shortcode and re-adding it is not the compatible with other plugins modifying galleries so instead you use the `post_gallery` filter hook and the same code from the `gallery_shortcode` function but with your own modification for example, I've commented out the parts you don't want:

```
function fix_my_gallery_wpse43558($output, $attr) {
    global $post;

    static $instance = 0;
    $instance++;


    /**
     *  will remove this since we don't want an endless loop going on here
     */
    // Allow plugins/themes to override the default gallery template.
    //$output = apply_filters('post_gallery', '', $attr);

    // We're trusting author input, so let's at least make sure it looks like a valid orderby statement
    if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
        $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
        if ( !$attr['orderby'] )
            unset( $attr['orderby'] );
    }

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
        'id'         => $post->ID,
        'itemtag'    => 'dl',
        'icontag'    => 'dt',
        'captiontag' => 'dd',
        'columns'    => 3,
        'size'       => 'thumbnail',
        'include'    => '',
        'exclude'    => ''
    ), $attr));

    $id = intval($id);
    if ( 'RAND' == $order )
        $orderby = 'none';

    if ( !empty($include) ) {
        $include = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $include );
        $_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );

        $attachments = array();
        foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
            $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
        }
    } elseif ( !empty($exclude) ) {
        $exclude = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $exclude );
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $exclude, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    } else {
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    }

    if ( empty($attachments) )
        return '';

    if ( is_feed() ) {
        $output = "\n";
        foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
            $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($att_id, $size, true) . "\n";
        return $output;
    }

    $itemtag = tag_escape($itemtag);
    $captiontag = tag_escape($captiontag);
    $columns = intval($columns);
    $itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor(100/$columns) : 100;
    $float = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

    $selector = "gallery-{$instance}";

    $gallery_style = $gallery_div = '';
    if ( apply_filters( 'use_default_gallery_style', true ) )
        /**
         * this is the css you want to remove
         *  #1 in question
         */
        /*
        $gallery_style = "
        <style type='text/css'>
            #{$selector} {
                margin: auto;
            }
            #{$selector} .gallery-item {
                float: {$float};
                margin-top: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                width: {$itemwidth}%;
            }
            #{$selector} img {
                border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
            }
            #{$selector} .gallery-caption {
                margin-left: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php -->";
        */
    $size_class = sanitize_html_class( $size );
    $gallery_div = "<div id='$selector' class='gallery galleryid-{$id} gallery-columns-{$columns} gallery-size-{$size_class}'>";
    $output = apply_filters( 'gallery_style', $gallery_style . "\n\t\t" . $gallery_div );

    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
        $link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false);

        $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
        $output .= "
            <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon'>
                $link
            </{$icontag}>";
        /*
         * This is the caption part so i'll comment that out
         * #2 in question
         */
        /*
        if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
            $output .= "
                <{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
                " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
                </{$captiontag}>";
        }*/
        $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
        if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
            $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
    }

    /**
     * this is the extra br you want to remove so we change it to jus closing div tag
     * #3 in question
     */
    /*$output .= "
            <br style='clear: both;' />
        </div>\n";
     */

    $output .= "</div>\n";
    return $output;
}
add_filter("post_gallery", "fix_my_gallery_wpse43558",10,2);
```

Comment: Actually, in the existing comment, see the long code under **EDIT**. It does the same :)

Comment: I can't see what you mean? where?

Comment: The first code block that starts with `function my_own_gallery($output, $attr) { ...`

Comment: Not really the code i posted has all of the issues you asked for (1,2,3) commented out and replaced.

Answer (score 8):

### See *[badlearner](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/10691/)'s* edit below

You can remove the default shortcode and create your own. Like so (in your functions.php):

```
remove_shortcode( 'gallery' );
function my_own_gallary() {
    // Gallery code
}
add_shortcode( 'gallery' , 'my_own_gallary' );
```

The easiest way to alter the shortcode is to copy paste it in your functions.php and change the function to name to something like `my_own_gallary` and begin editing.

---

### EDIT

As goldenapples in the comments pointed out:
There is a filter for the gallery shortcode, so no need to remove the shortcode first.

example you can use in your functions.php (output is as default gallery shortcode, so you can alter it).

```
function my_own_gallery($output, $attr) {
    global $post;

    static $instance = 0;
    $instance++;

    // We're trusting author input, so let's at least make sure it looks like a valid orderby statement
    if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
        $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
        if ( !$attr['orderby'] )
            unset( $attr['orderby'] );
    }

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
        'id'         => $post->ID,
        'itemtag'    => 'dl',
        'icontag'    => 'dt',
        'captiontag' => 'dd',
        'columns'    => 3,
        'size'       => 'thumbnail',
        'include'    => '',
        'exclude'    => ''
    ), $attr));

    $id = intval($id);
    if ( 'RAND' == $order )
        $orderby = 'none';

    if ( !empty($include) ) {
        $include = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $include );
        $_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );

        $attachments = array();
        foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
            $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
        }
    } elseif ( !empty($exclude) ) {
        $exclude = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $exclude );
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $exclude, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    } else {
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    }

    if ( empty($attachments) )
        return '';

    if ( is_feed() ) {
        $output = "\n";
        foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
            $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($att_id, $size, true) . "\n";
        return $output;
    }

    $itemtag = tag_escape($itemtag);
    $captiontag = tag_escape($captiontag);
    $columns = intval($columns);
    $itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor(100/$columns) : 100;
    $float = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

    $selector = "gallery-{$instance}";

    $gallery_style = $gallery_div = '';
    if ( apply_filters( 'use_default_gallery_style', true ) )
        $gallery_style = "
        <style type='text/css'>
            #{$selector} {
                margin: auto;
            }
            #{$selector} .gallery-item {
                float: {$float};
                margin-top: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                width: {$itemwidth}%;
            }
            #{$selector} img {
                border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
            }
            #{$selector} .gallery-caption {
                margin-left: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php -->";
    $size_class = sanitize_html_class( $size );
    $gallery_div = "<div id='$selector' class='gallery galleryid-{$id} gallery-columns-{$columns} gallery-size-{$size_class}'>";
    $output = apply_filters( 'gallery_style', $gallery_style . "\n\t\t" . $gallery_div );

    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
        $link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false);

        $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
        $output .= "
            <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon'>
                $link
            </{$icontag}>";
        if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
            $output .= "
                <{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
                " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
                </{$captiontag}>";
        }
        $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
        if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
            $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
    }

    $output .= "
            <br style='clear: both;' />
        </div>\n";

    return $output;
}
add_filter("post_gallery", "my_own_gallery",10,2);
```

---

Explanation:
In the shortcode defined by WordPress you will see:

```
$output = apply_filters('post_gallery', '', $attr);
    if ( $output != '' )
        return $output;
```

This means that if an filter is applied and returns something, that will be used (returned), otherwise the function continues (default shortcode).

To add a filter you use the [add_filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) function. The first argument is the tag of the filter (in this case 'post_gallery'), the second the function to add (the function that will return your custom gallery output).

So this will output "test" for the shortcode [gallery]:

```
function my_own_gallery($output, $attr) {
    return 'test';
}
add_filter("post_gallery", "my_own_gallery",10,2);
```

In my example below edit you will see the add_filter to create the default shortcode with your own editable code. You can edit this, or start from the ground up as you please.

---

(**EDIT by Otto:** The above has now been fixed by Otto. @RobVermeer was missing the first parameter to the filter and didn't do the add_filter correctly. The post_gallery filter is the correct way to do this. Removing the shortcode and re-adding it (as tried by *badlearner* below) is not advisable since it's incompatible with other plugins modifying galleries as well.)

---

## Added / Edited by [*badlearner*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/10691/):

The filter method of modifying the gallery code (in /wp-includes/media.php) using functions.php, as provided by @RobVermeer doesn't seem to be working properly (see this answer's comments).

But @RobVermeer's first answer (i.e., prior to first edit), which unregisters the gallery shortcode and registers a new gallery shortcode, worked. And here's the code, and ***Please feel free to edit or add an answer if there's a better way***.

The following is the code that needs to be added in your theme's functions.php file:

```
<?php
remove_shortcode( 'gallery' );
add_shortcode( 'gallery' , 'my_own_gallary' );
function my_own_gallary($attr) {
    global $post;

    static $instance = 0;
    $instance++;

    // Allow plugins/themes to override the default gallery template.
    $output = apply_filters('post_gallery', '', $attr);
    if ( $output != '' )
        return $output;

    // We're trusting author input, so let's at least make sure it looks like a valid orderby statement
    if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
        $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
        if ( !$attr['orderby'] )
            unset( $attr['orderby'] );
    }

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
        'id'         => $post->ID,
        'itemtag'    => 'dl',
        'icontag'    => 'dt',
        'captiontag' => 'dd',
        'columns'    => 3,
        'size'       => 'thumbnail',
        'include'    => '',
        'exclude'    => ''
    ), $attr));

    $id = intval($id);
    if ( 'RAND' == $order )
        $orderby = 'none';

    if ( !empty($include) ) {
        $include = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $include );
        $_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );

        $attachments = array();
        foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
            $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
        }
    } elseif ( !empty($exclude) ) {
        $exclude = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $exclude );
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $exclude, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    } else {
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    }

    if ( empty($attachments) )
        return '';

    if ( is_feed() ) {
        $output = "\n";
        foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
            $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($att_id, $size, true) . "\n";
        return $output;
    }

    $itemtag = tag_escape($itemtag);
    $captiontag = tag_escape($captiontag);
    $columns = intval($columns);
    $itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor(100/$columns) : 100;
    $float = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

    $selector = "gallery-{$instance}";

    $gallery_style = $gallery_div = '';
    if ( apply_filters( 'use_default_gallery_style', true ) )
        $gallery_style = "
        <style type='text/css'>
            #{$selector} .gallery-item {
                width: {$itemwidth}%;
            }
        </style>";
    $size_class = sanitize_html_class( $size );
    $gallery_div = "<div id='$selector' class='gallery galleryid-{$id} gallery-columns-{$columns} gallery-size-{$size_class}'>";
    $output = apply_filters( 'gallery_style', $gallery_style . "\n\t\t" . $gallery_div );

    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
        $link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false);

        $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
        $output .= "
            <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon'>
                $link
            </{$icontag}>";
        if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
            $output .= "";
        }
        $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
        if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
            $output .= '';
    }

    $output .= "
            <div style='clear:both;'></div>
        </div>\n";

    return $output;
}
?>
```

Comment: and what's the new shortcode for gallery going to be? `[gallery]` itself or something else?

Comment: is it going to be `[my_own_gallery]`??

Comment: `[gallery]` indeed. If you copy paste this in your function.php you will see exactly the same output in your posts. But if you edit the code you can make it your own.

Comment: You actually don't need to remove the entire shortcode and readd it. If you look near the top of WordPress's gallery function, there's a filter called 'post_gallery'. If that filter returns anything, WordPress will use it as the gallery output rather than its own output. So just add your markup as a filter on 'post_gallery'.

Comment: @goldenapples Overlooked that one. Thx, that is indeed the way to go.

Comment: going to steal this.  i hate the gallery AND especially the caption markups....

Comment: @goldenapples can you be a bit more clear? (I don't know how to code.) Maybe your own answer? please? Thanks.

Comment: @RobVermeer if what 'goldenapples' said made sense to you, can you please explain that as well by editing your answer? Thanks.

Comment: @RobVermeer & goldenapples: Thanks for helping me out! :)

Comment: Bit more info in my updated answer, hope this helps.

Comment: @RobVermeer It doesn't seem to be working on posts with multiple galleries. That is... when I put galleries of existing posts or pages in a new post using `[gallery id="n"]`, the galleries aren't being displayed. Instead all I see is the same image of the new post. Please see this page for instance: http://ow.ly/9ivOY.

Comment: @RobVermeer This is the original gallery code from /wp-includes/media.php : http://pastebin.com/JStF2V41 ... And this is what I am using in my functions.php : http://pastebin.com/1Q0iuvBn ... Can you please see if I am doing something wrong? (Please look for `<!--REMOVED CODE HERE-->` and `<!--CHANGED CODE HERE-->` tags in the latter.)

Comment: Both pastebin pages have the default shortcode in it?

Comment: @RobVermeer NO! Please look for `<!--REMOVED CODE HERE-->` and `<!--CHANGED CODE HERE-->` in the code and compare those in both documents. You'll notice the difference.

Comment: @RobVermeer Even the default code you provided doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @RobVermeer I have edited your answer, please see if you can help.

Comment: Your post_gallery filter function definition is wrong, and you're missing the numeric parameters for add_filter. I'll edit your answer to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

well its still there in the new version of wordpress as of 3.8
heres the fix i made to remove that used the same code above but added a couple of lines

```
remove_shortcode( "gallery" );
add_shortcode( "gallery" , "my_own_gallary" );
function my_own_gallary( $attr ) {
global $post;
static $instance = 0;
$instance++;
$output = apply_filters('post_gallery', '', $attr);
if ( $output != '' ) {
    return $output;
}
if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
    $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
    if ( !$attr['orderby'] )
        unset( $attr['orderby'] );
}
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
    'id'         => $post->ID,
    'itemtag'    => 'dl',
    'icontag'    => 'dt',
    'captiontag' => 'dd',
    'columns'    => 3,
    'size'       => 'thumbnail',
    'include'    => '',
    'exclude'    => ''
), $attr));
$id = intval($id);
if ( 'RAND' == $order ) {
    $orderby = 'none';
 }
if ( !empty($include) ) {
$include = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $include );
$_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    $attachments = array();
    foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
        $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
    }
} elseif ( !empty($exclude) ) {
    $exclude = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $exclude );
    $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $exclude, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
} else {
    $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
}
if ( empty($attachments) ) {
    return '';
}
if ( is_feed() ) {
    $output = "\n";
    foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
        $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($att_id, $size, true) . "\n";
    return $output;
}
$itemtag = tag_escape($itemtag);
$captiontag = tag_escape($captiontag);
$columns = intval($columns);
$itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor(100/$columns) : 100;
$float = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';
$selector = "gallery-".$instance;
$gallery_style = $gallery_div = '';
if ( apply_filters( 'use_default_gallery_style', true ) )
    $gallery_style = "
    <style type='text/css'>
        #".$selector." .gallery-item {
            width: ".$itemwidth."%;
        }
    </style>";
$size_class = sanitize_html_class( $size );
$gallery_div = "<div id='$selector' class='gallery galleryid-".$id." gallery-columns-".$columns." gallery-size-".$size_class."'>";
$output = apply_filters( 'gallery_style', $gallery_style . "\n\t\t" . $gallery_div );
$i = 0;
foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
$link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false);
$output .= "<".$itemtag." class='gallery-item'>";
$output .= "
        <".$icontag." class='gallery-icon'>
            $link
        </".$icontag.">";
/* added the <dd> here to fix validation error */
    if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
        $output .= "
            <".$captiontag." class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
            " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
            </".$captiontag.">";
    } else {
        $output .= "
            <".$captiontag." class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption' style='display:none;'></".$captiontag.">";
    }
    $output .= "</".$itemtag.">";
    if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
        $output .= '';
}

$output .= "
        <div style='clear:both;'></div>
    </div>\n";

return $output;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

`add_filter( 'use_default_gallery_style', '__return_false' );`

Comment: Please add a proper explanation to your answers to comply with the [wordpress.se] quality standards - for starters read [answer].