# gallery - size is thumbnail by default change it to medium

Tags: media

In wordpress gallery(through add media) when i create a gallery it default shows the thumbnail size image.

Instead of it i want to set to show the medium size image by default.

It is not good and takes lot of time to edit the old post for the tag manually:
`[gallery size="medium"]`

So i want to show the medium size by default. It can be through `functions.php`

Comment: Did you already check this question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56909/how-do-i-get-gallery-thumbnail-url-and-change-the-default-thumbnail-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below in you functions.php file,

```
add_filter('post_gallery','wpse56909_post_gallery',10,2);

function wpse56909_post_gallery($output, $attr) {
    // We're trusting author input, so let's at least make sure it looks like a valid orderby statement
    if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
        $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
        if ( !$attr['orderby'] )
            unset( $attr['orderby'] );
    }

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
        'id'         => $post->ID,
        'itemtag'    => 'dl',
        'icontag'    => 'dt',
        'captiontag' => 'dd',
        'columns'    => 3,
        'size'       => 'medium',
        'include'    => '',
        'exclude'    => ''
    ), $attr));

    $id = intval($id);
    if ( 'RAND' == $order )
        $orderby = 'none';

    if ( !empty($include) ) {
        $_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );

        $attachments = array();
        foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
            $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
        }
    } elseif ( !empty($exclude) ) {
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $exclude, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    } else {
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    }

    if ( empty($attachments) )
        return '';

    if ( is_feed() ) {
        $output = "\n";
        foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
            $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($att_id, $size, true) . "\n";
            return $output;
    }

    $itemtag = tag_escape($itemtag);
    $captiontag = tag_escape($captiontag);
    $icontag = tag_escape($icontag);
    $valid_tags = wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' );
    if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $itemtag ] ) )
        $itemtag = 'dl';
    if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $captiontag ] ) )
        $captiontag = 'dd';
    if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $icontag ] ) )
        $icontag = 'dt';

    $columns = intval($columns);
    $itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor(100/$columns) : 100;
    $float = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

    $selector = "gallery-{$instance}";

    $gallery_style = $gallery_div = '';
    if ( apply_filters( 'use_default_gallery_style', true ) )
        $gallery_style = "
            <style type='text/css'>
                #{$selector} {
                    margin: auto;
                }
                #{$selector} .gallery-item {
                    float: {$float};
                    margin-top: 10px;
                    text-align: center;
                    width: {$itemwidth}%;
                }
                #{$selector} img {
                    border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
                }
                #{$selector} .gallery-caption {
                    margin-left: 0;
                }
            </style>
            <!-- see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php -->";
    $size_class = sanitize_html_class( $size );
    $gallery_div = "<div id='$selector' class='gallery galleryid-{$id} gallery-columns-{$columns} gallery-size-{$size_class}'>";
    $output = apply_filters( 'gallery_style', $gallery_style . "\n\t\t" . $gallery_div );

    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
        $link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false);

        $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
        $output .= "
            <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon'>
                $link
            </{$icontag}>";
        if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
            $output .= "
                <{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
                    " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
                </{$captiontag}>";
        }
        $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
        if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
            $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
    }

    $output .= "
        <br style='clear: both;' />
        </div>\n";

    return $output;
}
```