# How to generate customized filtered output for the gallery

Tags: php, functions, filters, gallery

## Question →

Just like we customize the default `WordPress comment system` in the front end how can we customize this for the gallery the way we want to look this in the front-end?

Here it is mentioned →
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_gallery/

> If the filtered output isn’t empty, it will be used instead  of
>   generating the default gallery template.

My question is can someone give me an example how can I generate the output of my choice. should I create a whole template or should I deliver the output through some function in `functions.php`?

Comment: There isn't a simple answer. You need to rebuild the gallery shortcode entirely with your own markup. You can see the source for the shortcode function here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/gallery_shortcode/ That's your example. That filter gives you the attributes passed to the shortcode. The rest is *entirely* up to you. Haven't you asked this before?

Comment: I donmt think so that this is about shortcode, but this is about how to customize output of the WP default add media in posts.

Comment: When you add a gallery it adds a gallery shortcode to the page. Look at the Text view.

Comment: ok. Is there a way(hook) we can only change output instead of rewriting the whole shortcode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manually fix the WordPress gallery code using PHP in functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43558/how-to-manually-fix-the-wordpress-gallery-code-using-php-in-functions-php)